# Import Tag from xml file to another using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, getelementsbytagname, nodelist

I do my work with this piece and my problem is simple. Just changing the place of transfer. I did not know what is the matter responsible for determining the place of transportation in the first or last content.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = null;
Document doc = null;
Document doc2 = null;
String a = "E:\\1.xml" ;
String  c ;
try {
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = db.parse(new File(a));
    doc2 = db.parse(new File("E:\\L (1).xml"));
    NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("med");
    Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("end").item(0), true);
    NodeList nList2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("end");
    for (int i = f; i <g; i++) {
        c = +i+"" ;
        doc2 = db.parse(new File("E:\\L ("+c+").xml"));
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
            nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("end").item(temp), true);
             ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
        }  
    }
```

This is done from two files, and it works well, but the place of transferring the tag is at the end of the content. I want it at the beginning of the content

```
<med>
I move the Tag "dat" and it is moved at the end of the Tag "med" content
<dat>We have come to the wrong place, my friend</dat></med>

<med><dat>We want to get better here</dat>
I want to move Tag dat
To be the first content from Tag med
</med>
```

That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `appendChild` docs:

> Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node.

So it is adding it to the end as expected.

To insert it before any other element on that node, you can try:

```
ndListFirstFile.item(0).insertBefore(nodeArea, ndListFirstFile.item(0).getFirstChild());
```